# Is there a way to get controller from a node JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to populate a `VBox` using custom FXML layout.

Anyone know how to get access to controller so I can pass data?

```
public class Employee implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private VBox pnItems = null;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        Node[] nodes = new Node[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            try {

                final int j = i;
                nodes[i] = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Item.fxml"));

                //give the items some effect

                nodes[i].setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
                    nodes[j].setStyle("-fx-background-color : #0A0E3F");
                });
                nodes[i].setOnMouseExited(event -> {
                    nodes[j].setStyle("-fx-background-color : #02030A");
                });




                pnItems.getChildren().add(nodes[i]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Where is it broken?

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: @kas Take a look at the question/answers linked in my previous comment. You can get the controller from the `FXMLLoader` instance. If you need to get it later based on a `Node` you can store the relation in a `Map`.

Comment: i'm a new to java can you help me?

Comment: if you don't understand the other question, there's no way around going a step back and reading up on java :)

Comment: Unrelated to the issue: you're only using the array to refer to the nodes from the event handlers and you only refer to the node created in the same iteration. For this reason it's not necessary to use an array. Simply store the result of loading the fxml in a final variable and use that variable instead of refering to a element of the array: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { final Node node = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Item.fxml")); node.setOnMouseEntered(evt -> node.setStyle(...)); ... }`